# Emails not sent due to SMTP Exception

Tags: c#, email, smtpclient

I have a general mailbox that could be used to send emails from my website. It has stopped working and throws an exception. The following is a screenshot of the error.

[error http://img7.imageshack.us/img7/7227/42097647.png](http://img7.imageshack.us/img7/7227/42097647.png)

The code is

```
  protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    if (ValidateBox.Text == "6")
    {
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        message.From = new MailAddress(EmailBox.Text.ToString());
        message.To.Add(new MailAddress("praveendaniel86@gmail.com"));
        message.Subject = "Message via CAM Website General Mailbox";
        string body = "Name: " + NameBox.Text.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine +
                      "Home Tel: " + HomeTelBox.Text.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine +
                      "Work Tel: " + WorkTelBox.Text.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine +
                      "Comment/Question: " + CommentBox.Text.ToString();

        message.Body = body;


        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Send(message);

        Response.Redirect("~/Thank-You.aspx");
    }

    else
    {
        Label1.Visible = true;
    }



}
```

Could this be an error from the SMTP Client mentioned in my webconfig, How can I check if its working fine ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting up the [Network Credentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkcredential.aspx). In other words, you're not authenticating the email.

```
NetworkCredential myCredentials = new NetworkCredential(
"myemail@domain.com","myPassword","mail.myDomainName.com");


client.Credentials = myCredentials;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a configuration issue.

The SMTP server specified in your web.config (system.net > mailSettings > smtp) is not configured for relaying. You have two options to fix this:

1. Configure the SMTP server to allow relaying *for the IP address of your web server* (only!).
2. Send SMTP credentials with SmtpClient (see Dave's answer for that).